# Create global variable in angular js with directive to use jquery /js plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, plugins

Hi  I m using openseadragon api

i have directive with that code;

```
var viewer1 = OpenSeadragon({
    id: "img",
    prefixUrl: "",
    tileSources: {
        type: 'image',
        url:
    }
});
```

How can access the viewer variable to change opendragon object and add listeners  in other directive in my angular app ? for example to change image by `viewer1.open()`.

its related for any jquery/plugin implementation in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
window.viewer1 = OpenSeadragon({
         id: "img",
         prefixUrl: "",
         tileSources: {
         type: 'image',
         url: 
       }
});
```

Doing "window.viewer1" you assign the variable viewer1 to the window, that means is setted as global, so you can access it everywhere in the app (including jquery outside the directive or inside another directive via $window)

Comment: Yes but i have not reach the reputation limi  yet  :)